# Picker is not getting displayed in Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am very new to xamarin.
I was developing my First app in which,
a. First page displays userName, password and Login Button
b. Second page displays a drop down , so I used picker control.
But the picker is not displaying on my app screen.(SecondPage)

App.cs

```
 public class App : Application
{
     public App()
    {
        MainPage = new MainPage();

    }


    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    Entry UserName;
    Entry Password;
    Button LoginButton;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.Padding = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 20);
        StackLayout panel = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 15
        };


        panel.Children.Add(UserName = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter UserName",
        });

        panel.Children.Add(Password = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "Enter Password",
            IsPassword = true,
        });

        panel.Children.Add(LoginButton = new Button
        {
            Text = "Login",
            IsEnabled = true,
        });
        LoginButton.Clicked += OnLogin;
        this.Content = panel;


    }
    private async void OnLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SecondPage());
    }
}
```

SecondPage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
{

    public SecondPage()
    {

        StackLayout panel = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 15
        };

        panel.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = "Names of associates",
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label))
        });

        panel.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = "Remarks",
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label))
        });

        this.Content = panel;
    }
}
```

SecondPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout Padding ="10" Orientation="Vertical" >
<Picker x:Name="picker" Title="Select a monkey">
 <Picker.ItemsSource>
   <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
     <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
     <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
     <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
     <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
     <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
     <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
     <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
   </x:Array>
 </Picker.ItemsSource>
```

Any help is much appreciated..

Update 1: This works for me.But I wonder why I am getting exception when I use ItemSource.

SecondPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="RegisterApp.SecondPage"
         Title="Picker Test">
<StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Vertical" >
    <Picker Title="Select a monkey">
        <Picker.Items>
            <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
            <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
            <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
        </Picker.Items>
    </Picker>
 </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` of `StackLayout`?

Comment: You are defining your second page both in code behind and in XAML?

Comment: yes @Steve Chadbourne

Comment: Shouldn't it be one or the other? I think your XAML picker definition is being overwritten by your code behind definition.

Comment: I tried commenting the code behind , but still it is not working..

Comment: can you put your whole second xaml page in your question, not just the bit you are showing

Comment: Why you don't bind ItemsSource? Writing all values inside XAML isn't good practise.
Xamarin have some documentation about it:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource/#Populating_a_Picker_with_Data_Using_Data_Binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ScratchPad.Pages.MainPage"
             Title="Picker Test">

    <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Vertical" >
        <Picker x:Name="picker" Title="Select a monkey">
            <Picker.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                    <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
                    <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </Picker.ItemsSource>
        </Picker>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: This is throwing me an exception: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: No Property of name ItemsSource found

Comment: That's why I asked to see the whole page xaml - in case there was something else missing

Comment: Updated my question.Thank u so much